# webpack 5 load font-face import url

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

i read [assets management for loading fonts](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-fonts) and [css-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/), but couldn't get webpack to preserve the reference to the url where fonts-face are defined.

here is `style.css` which i import from my react application with import

```js
/* App.js */

import "./style.css";
```

this is how the `style.css` looks

```css
/* style.css */

@import url("https://url-to-some-xyz-font.css");

body {
  font-family: "xyz", monospace;
}
```

and this is my webpack configuration

```js
/* webpack.config.js */

{
  test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
  use: ["style-loader", "css-loader", "sass-loader"],
},
{
  test: /\.(woff(2)?|ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
  exclude: [/images/],
  type: "asset/resource",
  generator: {
    filename: "fonts/[name][ext]",
  },
},
```

how can i make webpack honor my `import url()` and embed it as is without having to download the fonts and reference them with `import url()` locally?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need sass-loader while you are dealing with css files.
Can you please try like this:

```js
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
}
```

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: 1. You are using a css file. So it is more suitable not to use `sass-loader`. Also more loader increases compile time.
2. You are using `@import` css rule in a css file.    
3. According to sass (dart-sass) `@import` is deprecated and has to be replaced with `@use` and `@forward` rules according to usage.    
4. [According to documentation](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import) It makes variables, mixins and functions globally accessible that makes difficult to tell where everything is defined.

Comment: this is good for optimization and did not change anything. i just had to update my packages.

Comment: @Mr. Can you tell me please is your problem solved?

Comment: yes, solved > i just had to update my packages. thank you